# Is there something like interface and abstract in Angular?

Tags: angular, abstract-class

I am working in Angular. I wanted to know if it has a similar class structure like java in terms of interface and Abstract classes.

Comment: Are you sure it is about Angual? Looks like your question is about [JavaScript] language. Please add proper tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular is using Typescript, the answer is Yes: check out this handbook: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

There are special rules for Component inheritance (template and style will not be inherited), check out this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2